# Angular: disable a formfield and keep form invalid

Tags: angular, validation, disable

I have a main form which embed a formArray

```
  initForm() {
    this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      label: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(this.labelMaxLength)]],
      foos: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    });
  }
```

foo is a subform (another component) :

```
  initForm() {
    this.subForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(this.labelMaxLength)]],
      bar: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    });
  }
```

in my process I need to disable the bar field temporally, which I perform with : this.subForm.get('bar').disable();

As expected, the field is disabled, and the associated validators are not taken into account anymore.

In my case, I need to keep the bar validator, or at least set the subForm invalid when bar is disabled.

I tried to do in the subcomponent `this.subForm.setErrors({incorrect: true});` but the main form consider the foos formArray valid and allow form submission...

thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the way to show error on bar is disabled you should make Validator for the FormGroup, like that:

```
this.subForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, ...]],
      bar: new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
    }, { validator: [barValidation] });
```

and make your custom validator:

```
export const barValidation: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const bar = control.get('bar');
  return bar.disabled ? { 'bar is disabled': true } : null;
};
```

Now FormGroup invalid when bar is disabled.

Comment: This is what I did, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What kind of form field is bar? If it's of input type, you can make it readonly instead of disabling it. That way your validator should work.

Also you can just simply check if bar is disabled or not and prevent form submission if disabled.